# Debug Odoo with Eclipse (Windows)

Tags: python, eclipse, windows, odoo

I'm trying to debug Odoo (V9) with Eclipse. The machine is a W7 (x64), with PostgreSQL 9.5, Python 2.7.11 (x64), Eclipse Mars with PyDev and EGit configured... i thing i've got everything, but it doesn't works.

This is the result when i launch it.

File "C:\Users\ELOY\workspace\OdooV9\odoo\openerp\tools\osutil.py", line 17, in 
    import win32service as ws
ImportError: DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado. (Can't find the specified module)

Answer (score 0):

Installing package pywin32 works for me

You will get setup from following links

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20214/pywin32-214.win32-py2.7.exe/download